# How to display the messages of sending and receiving based on time

Tags: css, reactjs

If a sender send a message it comes to right side of the ui and receiver gets from left side of the ui, but when a sender sends an another message to the receiver it should come display at the bottom end , but it shows at the top end

I want to be display the messages as

```
 received message
              send message
 received message
              send message
```

But here I'm getting the messages like

```
 received message
 received message
 received message
 received message
              send message
              send message
              send message
              send message
```

Here is the code:

```
        const time = new Date();
        const formattedTime = time.toLocaleString("en-US", { hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric", seconds: "numeric });

       <div className="nano-content pad-all" tabIndex={0} style={{right: '-17px'}}>
              <ul className="list-unstyled media-block">
              <li className="mar-btm" id="media-left">
              {
                receiveMessages.map((receivemessage,key) => {
                return <div>
                <div className="media-left">
                  <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" className="img-circle img-sm" alt="Profile Picture" />
                </div>
                <div className="media-body pad-hor">
                  <div className="speech">
                  <p value={key} className="mar-btm">{receivemessage}</p> 
                  <span class="time_date">{formattedTime}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
              })
              }
              </li>
              <li className="mar-btm" id="media-right">             
                {
                  messages.map((message,key) => {
                    return <div>
                  <div className="media-right">
                    <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png" className="img-circle img-sm" alt="Profile Picture" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="media-body pad-hor speech-right mt-2">
                    <div className="speech">  
                    <p value={key} className="mar-btm">{message}</p>  
                    <span class="time_date">{formattedTime}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                  })
                }       
                </li>
               </ul>
          </div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to merge the arrays by time. Can you show what these arrays look like as part of a [mcve]? Showing the full component without the irrelevant styling would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are just mapping one array after the other, so the messages are expected to show like they are.
Instead of just an array of message strings you'd need a more complex object with some metadata: (1) the date the message was sent. (2) who sent it, and of course (3) the message itself. Like:

```
messsageObj = {
  // always good to add an unique id to use as the `key` property when using .map
  id: 1, 
  message: 'My message',
  createDate: '25/12/2020 22:00:00',
  createUser: 1
}
```

For example:

```
// in `mergeMessagesArray` you add all messages to a single list, 
// ordering by the date they were sent
const mergedMessages = mergeMessagesArray(sentMessages, receivedMessages)

return (
  <div>
    {mergedMessages.map(m => (
      // use unique id as key to avoid weird bugs
      <div key={m.id}
        // when mapping the messages array just check the user who created the 
        // message against your current logged in user and render accordingly
        className={m.createUser === currentUser ? 'show-on-right' : 'show-on-left'}>
       {m.message}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
)
```